# CSS: remove spacing before and after display:block nested in <pre>

Tags: css, spacing, line-spacing

I want to display a consecutive series of `<pre>` elements without any blank space between them (like consecutive lines of a same paragraph).

I can't achieve that while having `display: block`

Here is a sample code

```css
body {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: auto;
}

pre {
    display:block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    padding: 0
}
```

```html
<p>One-line paragraph.</p>
<pre>One-line pre element, without space before or after.</pre>
<pre>Another pre line.</pre>
<p>Some paragraph.</p>

<!-- EDIT: the actual problematic code : nested pre -->

<pre>
<pre>One-line pre element, without space before or after.</pre>
<pre>Another pre line.</pre>
</pre>
```

I wish the output would simply have no large interline between each line

NOTE: using `display:inline` works, but I need to use block because I want the `pre` lines to be larger than `body`.

**EDIT**: I realise this code snippets displays correctly in Stackoverflow, which is not the case of my larger document:

Explanation found (see updated code): pre lines were already nested in pre element. In this case, the CSS solution is to use `display: inline-block`

Comment: have you tried `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: thanks. No it does not suppress blanks.

Comment: Browsers usually give `<p>` elements a top and bottom margin by default. Using `p { margin: 0; }` may do what you desire.

Comment: Please provide a playground link of your code to check more specifically

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve this with the `float: left` CSS property:

```css
pre:not(.parent) {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent pre {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left; /* new line */
}
```

```html
<p>One-line paragraph.</p>
<pre>One-line pre element, without space before or after.</pre>
<pre>Another pre line.</pre>
<p>Some paragraph.</p>

<!-- EDIT: the actual problematic code : nested pre -->

<pre class="parent">
<pre>One-line pre element, without space before or after.</pre>
<pre>Another pre line.</pre>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the margin of the paragraph tag.

```css
body {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: auto;
}

pre {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin: 0;
    /* padding: 0; */ /* does nothing */
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>one-line paragraph</p>
<pre>one-line pre element, without space before or after</pre>
<pre>another pre line</pre>
<p>some paragraph</p>
```

According to **[W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)**, this is the default styling for paragraph elements:
`margin: 1.12em 0`

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong in my question: actually in the stackoverflow snippet, we see that the output is already correct between the two `<pre>` lines. But I have a larger document in which *consecutive* `<pre>` lines are spaced by blanks, unless I use the `display: inline-block`... No idea what's happening

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong you need to reproduce the issue that you are seeing or else there is no way for us to know what problem you are having

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was turning in circles so I posted here. But I found the problem (nesting pre) and so there is a solution. See the updated question.